# How to create a generic type for an arrow function in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript-typings

I try to write typescript functions in the style that is most close to functional. For simple functions I can write:

```
type A = (value: number) => string;
const a: A = value => value.toString();
```

But what can I do with generic types? How can I type in that simple way following function?

```
function a<T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
```

If I try to simply add a generic type, it gives nothing:

```
type A = <T>(value: T) => T;
const a: A = value => value; // `value` implicitly has an `any` type
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your last snippet:

```
type A = <T>(value: T) => T;
const a: A = value => value;
```

You tell the compiler that `a` is of type `A`, but you don't bind it to a specific generic type which is why it uses `any`.

For example, you can set the generic type like so:

```
const a: A = (value: string) => value;
```

You can also do this:

```
type A<T> = (value: T) => T;
const a: A<string> = value => value;
```

If you want `a` to be specific.

If you want `a` to stay generic you'll need to declare the generic constraint on it as well:

```
const a: A = <T>(value: T) => value;
```

Comment: So, the clear callback that is not specific without parenthesis is not allowed, right?

Comment: It is allowed, you're not getting any errors right?

Comment: Well, except the value becames `any`, and it is not allowed by my tsconfig.json. Anyway, thank you, the answer helped me.

Comment: What version of typescript does this work with? I am on the typescript playground and your solution still shows errors. I have tried down to version 3.3, and they all show errors...

Comment: @smac89 yeah, getting errors as well. based on the date of the answer i'd say that it was using version `2.2`